# Java Generic class doesn't display the objects i pass into it

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to build a simple generic class that uses generic objects in java. everything compiles fine, but when i run the code, it doesn't display the objects i passed to it.

Here is my code:

```
public class ListDriver {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> glist = new List<String>(10);

        glist.add("milk");
        glist.add("eggs");
        System.out.println("Grocery List" + glist.toString());

    }


    public class List<T> {
        private T[] datastore;
        private int size;
        private int pos;


        public List(int numElements) {
            size = numElements;
            pos = 0;
            datastore = (T[]) new Object[size];
        }

        public void add(T element) {
            datastore[pos] = element;

        }

        public String toString() {
            String elements = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < pos; ++i) {
                elements += datastore[i] + "";
            }
            return elements;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Format your code. It's ugly.

Comment: What results do you get?  Have you tried debugging?  Also, the value of pos never changes after initialization in the constructor.

Comment: `datastore[pos] = element;` ==> `datastore[pos++] = element;`. Also, you should compare `pos` with `size`, and grow `datastore` as necessary.

Comment: thank you all very much for your help. It worked. i forgot to increment [pos++]

Comment: Then choose one of the answers, to mark the question as answered, or delete it (as you prefer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't increment your `pos` variable, so you're always adding in the same place. Try

```
public void add(T element) {
        datastore[pos++] = element;

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your add method always replaces the element in position 0 (zero). You forgot to increment pos (`pos++;`)

Comment: I'd have chosen yours either, because you added the method already corrected ;)